# Capturing DOM Value using GTM

Tags: dom, web-scraping, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

Total noob here so please bear with me:

I am trying to setup dynamic FB remarketing on a client ecommerce site.The problem is that the site doesn't have a data layer setup for this process so I'm trying to scrape some ecommerce values from the DOM (specifically the product name).

Essentially I am trying to capture the product name from this code string from the order confirmation page:

```
<h3> <p> <a href="/product/79530/icebreaker-pocket-hat" title="Show details for "> **Icebreaker&#174; Pocket Hat - Black/Cargo** </a> </p> </h3>
```

The "Icebreaker® Pocket Hat - Black Cargo" is what I'm trying to feed into a custom FB pixel as a DOM variable in GTM. I've been experimenting all sorts of things but nothing has really worked so far. I've already captured order value this way so I'm fairly confident this is at least possible.

On the same order confirmation page, there is also this bit of JavaScript with the product name in it should that be of use as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var gbTracker = new GbTracker('cabelasca', 'Production'); gbTracker.autoSetVisitor(); var visitorId = gbTracker.getVisitorId(); var sessionId = gbTracker.getSessionId(); gbTracker.sendOrderEvent({ cart: { items: [ { productId: '79530', title: '**Icebreaker® Pocket Hat - Black/Cargo**', price: 24.97, quantity: 1 }, ] } }); </script>
```

I am hoping someone knows how to pass this value using some kind of custom GTM variable. Any nudge towards an answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

What I would normally do if I need to get some data from DOM is:

**Create DOM element variable**

This variable will find all necessary data from DOM. For example in your case variable should be like that:

[image]

CSS selector: `h3 > p > a`

**Use this variable in your tags**

Then in your tags just use this variable like that: `{{Product Title}}`